# Changing components based on state

Tags: react-native, render

I'm working in react-native. I have a form page in my mobile app and have an edit button and back button. Once the edit button is clicked, I want a save and cancel button to replace the edit and back button, and they should have their own functionality. I have tried `componentWillUpdate()` and `if else` statements in my render function, but neither seem to work.

Comment: You don't need to use the lifecycle functions for something like this. Simply have a `state` variable to control the edit mode and render the button conditionally. For example `onPress={() => { this.setState({ editing: true }) }` and `{this.state.editing && <BackButton />}`. React will look after the re-rendering based on changes to state. Also, please post some code!

Comment: Thanks! Was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the buttons in your render function, controlled with state(eg. inEditMode). When user click on edit button you can set inEditMode to true and display the edit & back button.

Something like this:

```js
   render() {
     this.state.inEditMode ? 
       <View>
          <EditButton />
          <BackButton />
       </View> :
       <View>
          <CancelButton />
          <SaveButton />
       </View>
   }
```